# quantile rank formula

Tags: descriptive-statistics

I am teaching a basic statistics course for psychology students. The lecturer provided a formula for the rank of a quantile rank = alpha n + 1/2, alpha being the proportion which corresponds to the quantile and $n$ the number of observations
The students asked why it is a half for all quantiles. Is this so that you always round up to the next integer? Basically I am looking for an intuitive explanation for this formula and would like to know if it works in all cases and for all quantiles.
Cheers!

Comment: "rank of a quantile rank" seems like an odd phrase.  Can you clarify?

Comment: sorry should have been: 
"rank of a quantile. Rank = alpha n + 1/2"